# React - fetch data and store in a variable

Tags: reactjs

Beginner with react and struggling with something that I am sure is probably very simple. I am just trying to make a simple component that will fetch data and display a part of it in a div.  I am able to get the data and print it to console, but I am having trouble saving to a variable and displaying it. Here is my code (removed the actual url for privacy reasons):

```
let x = -1;
function getData(apiUrl){
    fetch(apiUrl, {credentials: 'same-origin'})
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                Logging.error(`Did not get an ok. got: ${response.statusText}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(json => {x = json.value})
        .catch((error) => {
            Logging.error(`Error getting ad data: ${error.message}`);
        })
}

const MyPage = () => {
    getData('my endpoint')
    return (
        <div>{x}</div>
    );
}
```

My issue is when I load the page it always displays my default value of "-1". So either x is never getting re-assigned, or the return is happening before it does.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Answer (score 3):

Other commenters about setting state is not wrong.

However, you are also not exactly wrong, expecting a value for x.

1. Your getData function calls fetch, however you did not return anything from fetch. If you want to use **x = getData()**, you will need to ensure to add a return before the fetch function in order to return the data.

   ```
   const getData = (apiUrl) => {

    return fetch(apiUrl, {credentials: 'same-origin'})
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                Logging.error(`Did not get an ok. got: ${response.statusText}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(json => {x = json.value})
        .catch((error) => {
            Logging.error(`Error getting ad data: ${error.message}`);
        })
   }

   let x = await getData(apiUrl)
   ```

However, fetch is **asynchronous** so it's you need to use **x = await getData()**.

2. You cannot use await outside an async function, so you need to use effect, and useState to properly render the data you want.

   ```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


    const MyPage = () => {
    const [ data, setData ] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        getData(apiUrl);
    },[])
           const getData = async (apiUrl) => {

         fetch(apiUrl, {credentials: 'same-origin'})
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    Logging.error(`Did not get an ok. got: ${response.statusText}`);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(json => setData(json)) //setData here
            .catch((error) => {
                Logging.error(`Error getting ad data: ${error.message}`);
            })
       }

      return (<pre>{ JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)}</pre>)
      }
   ```

You need to use JSON.stringify to show your JSON results in your return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to you use the state in react. Try something like:

```
import react, { useState, useEfect } from 'react';

const MyPage = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    const useEfect(() => {
        const result = getData('my endpoint');
        setData(result);
     }, []);

        return (
            <div>{data}</div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the answer to use newest async/await without mixing older Promise .then syntax as seen in other answers.

```
  const getDataAsync = async (apiURL) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(apiURL, {credentials: 'same-origin'});
      if (response.ok) {
        const responseJson = await response.json();
        setData(responseJson);
      } else {
        Logging.error(`Did not get an ok. got ${response.statusText}`);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Logging.error(`Error getting ad data: ${e}`);
    }
  };
```